# Using a different view in editing mode in a view based NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I have a `NSTableView` with a single `NSTableCellView` column that let's say, has an icon, name and an optional date.

When you edit a row, I want to replace the whole view with a simple `NSTextField`, and I will do some parsing to that text and extract that optional date, if present.

My question is, how would you implement this editing mechanism?

I tried returning a different view in the `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row`, something like:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn    *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    BOOL isSelected = [tableView isRowSelected:row];


    if (isSelected) 
    {
        NSView *view = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"editor" owner:self];

        ....snip....

        return view;
    }
    else
    {
        TaskView *view = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"view" owner:self];

        ....snip....

        return view;
    }
}
```

and then whenever the selected row changes, trying to request a refresh on that row.

```
- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSTableView *table = [aNotification object];

    NSUInteger rowIndex = [table selectedRow];

    [table reloadDataForRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:rowIndex]  
                     columnIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];

}
```

It doesn't quite work, and the code feels a bit dirty.
It must be a better way of doing this, and I can't seem to find in the docs or online.